# Join two dataframes on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes with names df1 and df2.

df1=

```
   col1   col2  count
0   1      36   200
1   12     15   200
2   13     17   100
```

df2=

```
    product_id  product_name
0      1            abc
1      2            xyz
2      3            aaaa
3      12           qwert 
4      13           sed
5      15           qase
6      36           asdf
7      17           zxcv
```

The entries in **col1 and col2** are **product_id from df2.**

I want to make a new dataframe 'df3', which has the following columns and entries.

df3=

```
   col1 | col1_name | col2 | col2_name | count
0   1   |   abc     |   36 |    asdf   |  200
1   12  |   qwert   |   15 |    qase   |  200
2   13  |   sed     |   17 |    zxcv   |  100
```

i.e add a `col1_name` and `col2_name` wherever `product_id` from `df2` is equal to `col1` & `col2` values.

Is it possible to do so with:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

My knowledge of Pandas df and Python is beginner level.
Is there a way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` generated from `df2` and then sort columns names by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
d = df2.set_index('product_id')['product_name'].to_dict()
print (d)
{1: 'abc', 2: 'xyz', 3: 'aaaa', 36: 'asdf', 17: 'zxcv', 12: 'qwert', 13: 'sed', 15: 'qase'}

df1['col1_name'] = df1.col1.map(d)
df1['col2_name'] = df1.col2.map(d)
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df1)
   col1 col1_name  col2 col2_name  count
0     1       abc    36      asdf    200
1    12     qwert    15      qase    200
2    13       sed    17      zxcv    100
```

---

```
df1 = df1.drop(['col1','col2'], axis=1)
print (df1)
  col1_name col2_name  count
0       abc      asdf    200
1     qwert      qase    200
2       sed      zxcv    100
```

Comment: yes sir,this is working, apart from that , if i only want to display `col1_name | col2_name | count` in my final result. is there a better way than to `df1.drop('col1','col2')`

Comment: appreciated,a nice solution using map()

Comment: i tried using the same logic on a bigger set of data and my col1_name and col2_name are coming NaN

Comment: You get `NaN` if some values are not in `df2`.

Comment: You can test it with sample and `d = {1: 'abc', 2: 'xyz', 3: 'aaaa'}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128442/discussion-between-s-ringne-and-jezrael).

Comment: Sir, i don't know why it's not working, it gave right results when i tested it with the dummy dataset i provided in the question, but with my real dataset ,its giving NAN in all the columns, which i crosschecked with df2 and it has the names
instead of using a map() function, can you provide me a way using .apply()

Comment: Can you please check discussion? i've elaborated my issue much better.

Comment: sorry, dinner. Please check discussion.

Comment: But I think there is problem column `product_id` or columns `col1` or `col2` are different `dtypes` - in one `DataFrame` are `object` (it is obviously `string`) and in another `int`. You need cast all to same `dtypes`, e.g. all convert to string by  [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) `df1.col1 = df1.col1.astype(str)`, `df1.col2 = df1.col2.astype(str)` and `df2.product_id = df2.product_id.astype(str)`

Comment: yeah, that was the issue , i too figured it out,

Comment: it works fine,just had to rearrange the column names.

Comment: rearrange ? Can you help you?

Comment: only the `count` column came at the start so i rearranged my dataframe columns. [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712989/find-count-of-combinations-of-column-in-pandas-df/40713284#40713284)

Comment: `df2 = df.groupby(['product_id_x']).size()` i ran this query, and got the count, but i want it to be in a different column in my df

Comment: Maybe need `reset_index` like `df.groupby(['product_id_x', 'product_id_y']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()`