# Find count of combinations of column in pandas df

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
product_id_x   product_id_y
1              2
1              3
1              4
3              7
3              11
3              14
3              2
and so on around (1000 rows)
```

i want to find the count of combinations for each product_id_x with product_id_y.

ie. 1 has combinations with 1-2,1-3,1-4(total 3 combinations)
similarly 3 has total 4 combinations.

and create a dataframe df2 which has

```
product_id_x   combinations
1               3
3               4

and so on ..(distinct product_id_x's)
```

what approach should i follow?
my skills on python are at a beginner level.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby` with `agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) on `product_id_x` column:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['product_id_x']).agg(['count'])
```

Or, you can directly use `size` function on the group to get size of each group:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['product_id_x']).size()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Once you have grouped you will get only one row corresponding to each `product_id_x`. How do you want to display `product_id_y` in this case?

Comment: i tried your `df2 = df.groupby(['product_id_x']).size()` code, and i modified it to `df2['count'] = dataFrame.groupby(['product_id_x']).size()` since i wanted a column name for the size, but still the column name is not showing

Answer (score 2):

`size` counts the number of rows each of the column value pairs happen together.  `count` counts the same thing but where they are not null.  Since you did not mention anything about nulls, I'll use `size` after a `groupby`, then `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['product_id_x', 'product_id_y']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]